# Notice: Undefined index: in C:\wamp\www\tests\Joomla\Website\index.php on line 37

Tags: php, notice

Hey i get this  : Notice: Undefined index: in C:\wamp\www\tests\Joomla\Website\index.php on line 37

And my code is this :

```
<?php 
    $remarks=$_GET['remarks'];

    if ($remarks==null and $remarks=="")
    {
        echo '';
    }
    if ($remarks=='success')
    {
        echo 'Registration Success';
    }
?>
```

I don't understand why i get this . Please help!

Comment: It would help for you to identify what line in your code is `line 37`. Your HTML is also not needed in the post, as this is a PHP error.

Comment: also, the line if ($remarks==null and $remarks=="") should probably have an OR instead of the AND (as $remarks can't be null and "" at the same time):

if ($remarks==null or $remarks=="")

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't say where is the line 37... I ain't a wizard, but I can guess from the error...

Since the error is `Undefined index`, that must come from the line:

```
$remarks=$_GET['remarks'];
```

You should validate that `$_GET['remarks']` is not null with `isset($_GET['remarks'])` before trying to get it's value.

Second, that line does not make any sence, since the `$remarks` can never be `null` and `""`:

```
 if ($remarks==null and $remarks=="")
```

So I would write the code like this:

```
<?php 
    $remarks = "";
    if ( isset($_GET['remarks']) ) {
        $remarks = $_GET['remarks'];
    }

    if ( $remarks == 'success' ) {
        echo 'Registration Success';
    }
?>
```